# Getting the length of line inside polygon

Tags: polygon, line, overlapping-features, postgis-2.0, length

How can I get the length (brown marked part) of the "Road 7" inside the red polygon?

[image: a busy cat]

My start:

```sql
SELECT ST_Length(way)
FROM lines
WHERE road = "Road 7" AND ST_Intersects(line, polygon)
```

with that, I get only the total length. Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's necessary to calculate the actual intersection, e.g. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html

```
SELECT ST_Length(ST_Intersection(line,polygon))
```

Comment: You beat me to it. +1 this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternavite method for the mulitpoints in polygon

```
 SELECT
    sum(ST_LENGTH(ST_Intersection(tr.geom, pd.geom), false)/1000) as km
    FROM roads as tr,
    polygon as pd
    WHERE ST_Intersects(pd.geom, tr.geom);
```